# FFT in python not giving the expected result

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing, fft

lately i've been trying to calculate the FFT of an signal via python.
The problem is, i'm only getting the fundamental frequency in the fft graph. as it follows:

[image]

If we look the "Sinal" plot, there's far more harmononics then i get in the FFT. I'm compared the waveform with the osciloscope, and seems equal, but the FFT is very different from the one calculated by the osciloscope. Also, i don't know why the FFT seems so clean.

I'm using this code.

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import fft, signal
import csv

with open('output.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    data=[]
    time=[]

    count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        data.append(row)
        count += 1
    i = 0
    rec_data = []
    data = numpy.array(data)
    while i < count:
        rec_data.append(float(data[i]))
        i+=1
    
    recv_data = rec_data - numpy.mean(rec_data)

    time_step = 1/9835
    fft_transform_complex = fft.fft(recv_data)
    print(fft_transform_complex)
    fourrier_transform = 2/50000 * numpy.abs(fft_transform_complex) #Tira o módulo e normaliza o valor
    sample_frequencies = fft.fftfreq(50000, time_step)
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1, constrained_layout=True)
    fig.suptitle('Sinal e FFT')
    axs[0].plot(recv_data)
    # O filtro atrasa o sinal, por isso não pode pegar o sinal no começo
    axs[0].set_xlim([0,450])
    axs[0].set_title('Sinal')
    axs[0].set_ylabel('Corrente [A]')
    axs[0].set_xlabel('Amostra [n]')
    axs[1].plot(sample_frequencies, fourrier_transform)
    axs[1].set_xlim([0,300])
    axs[1].set_title('FFT')
    axs[1].set_ylabel('Amplitude')
    axs[1].set_xlabel('Frequência [Hz]')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: Much of your code is tied up in ingestion of data that you didn't supply.  Hard-code that data, and supply the alternate FFT result to which you're comparing.

Comment: Sorry, this link contains the csv file that outputs this data. [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TVMp-pr4WGxX72J_DM5X8ha6i5FDiirE/view?usp=sharing) . The osciloscope data is avaiable here [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TVMp-pr4WGxX72J_DM5X8ha6i5FDiirE/view?usp=sharing) . I can't use the osciloscope data on my program yet, since the sample rate is diferent.

Comment: Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; your posting must be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, `matplotlib` has a built-in method for generating magnitude spectrum plots, saving you a lot of guessing as to where a bug might exist.
All your FFT code can be replaced with something like:

```py
Fs = 9835
axs[1].magnitude_spectrum(recv_data, Fs, sides='onesided')
axs[1].set_xlim([0,500])
axs[1].set_title('FFT')
axs[1].set_ylabel('Amplitude')
axs[1].set_xlabel('Frequência [Hz]')
```

`magnitude_spectrum` will perform the FFT as well.

Most likely, the Y-axis scaling might be off compared to your oscilloscope.
You're plotting your FFT using a linear scale, but it's more common for tools to use a logarithmic dB scale.

Try:
`axs[1].magnitude_spectrum(recv_data, Fs, sides='onesided', scale='dB')`
and you'll get something more like

[image: Output of magnitude_spectrum using dB scale]

If that's not close, it's unlikely that your oscilloscope is doing the FFT on the entire 50k samples at once. Try changing the magnitude_spectrum call to something like:

`axs[1].magnitude_spectrum(recv_data[0:1024], Fs, sides='onesided', scale='dB')`

It may closer match what you're seeing in the oscilloscope.

Comment: Thank you very much, i really forgot the log part. Also, this built-in method saves a lot work, really nice! Again, big thanks.